# How can i embedded aparat video in eclipse without relative?

Tags: android-webview, embedded-resource, video-embedding, eclipse-api

I want to add movies in my app how can i embedded them in my app without relative movies at end ? 
my Movies uploaded in aparat (like youtube ) .

Comment: Please show some effort by editing your question and explain what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Btw you should take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) first  and also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)